# Combine HTML site with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a website i coded alone with HTML, CSS, JS and JQuery, and I want to add service payment functionality (not e-shop with items, but give clients the ability to submit forms, pay on the website and receive the appropriate services online, so they don't have to come on-site. I want to use WordPress so I can use the woocommerce plugin, cause I'm feeling that's a safer option that coding something myself. How can i get my site and woocommerce working together without having to create the website again using plugins? I know that i can add code blocks, but that means I'll have to keep the title panel on top of the page, and I find that unappealing, and the plugins that exist for removing those aren't a great solution imo. can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my personal opinion, you can do this by simply installing wordpress and then a basic theme. then installing all you need for your woocommerce. then a link that goes to the woocommerce whenever it needs to go there. It is not really a big deal.

Eg a menu that says `buy now` with a link to woocommerce and predefined amount. so when the user clicks the `buy now` button, it goes to woocommerce to continue.

so your website will be in 2 parts. a part for information (Your HTML Site) and a place for interactions (Wordpress).

Some websites have similar instances where depending on what you are doing the theme changes.

I however will recommend you go through the pain of doing your whole site on wordpress or simply finding other options to integrate the payments you want to in your current design.

This is for a uniformed design and will make your users/clients feel more secured instead of feeling they are being moved through sites.

Comment: I agree with the last idea, but my issue is that its (other than a business website) a project, I would much rather write the code myself. The peyment integration isn't my issue because there will be a redirect to the Bank's webpage for a secure transaction, so I wont be handling any sensitive information there. My concern is with how I will be receiving and sending sensitive info like client details and documents wihout creating any serious security concerns. I might have to look into that for creating my forms and just integrating them into my existing website instead. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i will wait for 1 or 2 hrs before I accept your answer, in case theres anyone with any other recommendations.

Comment: The security concerns part is very important. with all the privacy policies these days, one can never take that lightly. I believe even with a wordpress installed, you may stil be open to attacks. you would just have to do due diligence on every plugin/code you decide to use at any point. ...and now fingers crossed for the next couple of hours. :)

Comment: exactly, I am already looking for all the legal mumbo jumbo that I need to add to my page to be GDPR compliant, I'm going from a simple website that only shows info, not using cookies or anything fancy like that to basically the complete opposite side of the spectrum... web development just got a whole lot harder...